# How can I replicate performance counter setups in an Azure WorkerRole?

Tags: performance, deployment, performance-monitoring, azure, performance-counters

I am trying to collect performance statistics on our Azure application.  Up till now, our process has been to set up the roles with RDP enabled, connect, manually set up the performance counters, log out, and then deploy the app to the running roles.

Ideally I would like to have this perf config as a startup task in the `.csdef` I deploy with so that it happens automagically.

In trying to determine how to save and load a set of performance counters, I came across this article that recommends the `lodctr` utility:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/yongrhee/archive/2009/10/06/how-to-rebuild-performance-counters-on-windows-vista-server2008-7-server2008r2.aspx

The comments in the article though are making me leery about trying to use that tool.

Answer (score 0):

I later found these articles, which describe the process for setting up counters in the role `OnStart()` method, as well as deploying additional counters to a running deployment using PowerShell.

[Setting Up Performance Counters In Your Azure Web and Worker Roles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walterm/archive/2011/02/01/setting-up-performance-counters-in-your-web-and-worker-roles.aspx)

[Automated Performance Counter Injection in Windows Azure Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh824676.aspx)